# Circle radius based on zoom level in Mapbox GL JS map

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

I have a custom map (with image overlay) with the GeoJSON data:
[image: Screenshot 1]

I need to add a mouseclick handler to the object circle (the gate on my map). It's all right for polygon areas (each corner has its own geo-coordinates), and I can handle the click, but for the circle I have a problem, because I only have the coordinates of the circle's center and the radius of the circle in pixels. When I scale the map, the circle has a different size from the object.
[image: 1] [image: 2]

How to make the radius depends on the zoom level?

P.S. Mapbox GL JS has support of a functions (expressions) in the radius value but I understand what I need to use.

Comment: Mapbox should provide a way to define user interaction events such as zoom. Having a handler on this event will help you change radius of clickable area

Comment: Mapbox has support of expressions/functions in values (e.g. radius), there is no need to use any handlers but I don't understans, what I should use.

Comment: @VeroLom I correctly understand that the gate is not a geo-json object, but drawn on the map itself?

Comment: @stdob-- yes, you are right.

Comment: @VeroLom It seems to me that it will be easier to interpolate a circle around an object using polygons: https://jsfiddle.net/6qbdcofs/

Comment: @stdob-- Thank you, I'll try.